# CSS/LESS when > something AND < something

Tags: css, conditional-statements, less-mixins

I'm trying to set a property when a value is less than AND greater than, to set a window for the property to apply.

Example:

```
.mixin (@colorVal) when (lightness(@colorVal) > 75%) {color:red;}
.mixin (@colorVal) when (lightness(@colorVal) > 25%) {color:green;}
.mixin (@colorVal) when (lightness(@colorVal) <= 75%) {color:green;}
.mixin (@colorVal) when (lightness(@colorVal) <= 25%) {color:blue;}
```

I can't quite figure out how to combine guards. In the example above, a color with a lightness of 20% would have both the 3rd and 4th guards apply. So it would compile a color of both green and then blue. That technically renders correctly due to the order, but still kind of messy...

Any alternative solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the LESSCSS docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-logical-operators)

> You can use logical operators with guards. The syntax is based on CSS media queries.
>
> Use the and keyword to combine guards:
>
> ```
> .mixin (@a) when (isnumber(@a)) and (@a > 0) { ... }
> ```

So for your case use:

```
.mixin (@colorVal) when (lightness(@colorVal) > 25%) and (lightness(@colorVal) < = 75%) {
    color:green;
}
```